# relation symbols as arrows in xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic

Is there a way to put a relation symbol (appropriately oriented) as the arrow in an xymatrix diagram?  For example, a lattice of sets with the subset relation symbol pointing from the subset to the superset.

Comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution — I can't do anything better without a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\newdir{d}{{\subset}}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
  A \ar@{}[r]|{\subset} & B\\
  A \ar@{-*{\subset}}[r] & B\\
  A \ar@{-d}[r] & B\\
  A \ar@{-d}[r]-<10pt,0pt> & B
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

The `\newdir` command allows to define shorthand.

And the result :
[image]

Note that you can find some help in the [xyguide](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy-3.8.6/doc/xyguide.pdf) pages 5 and 6.

Comment: Very helpful, thankyou!  Is there a way to get the orientation of the \subset to match the direction of the arrow?  e.g. if the arrow is pointing up rather than right, as in your examples.

Comment: @Alex I had a look to xy.tex to see how the original tips are defined, but the code is not really readable. Maybe you can ask your question on the xy mailing list.

Comment: @Alex A solution is to rotate manually the symbol, put it's not a good solution. I tried to create a new tips from the existing ones as this solution has the orientation done automatically. Unfortunately, I didn't succeed to create a tips that looks like the subset symbol.

Comment: The solution I gave here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279231/vertical-cong-or-sym-in-xymatrix/348673#348673 successfully rotates any symbol using only the language of xy-pic.