# vertical $\cong$ or $\sym$ in xymatrix

Tags: xy-pic

I need to show that a certain vertical arrow in a commutative diagram is an isomorphism. I would like to either add a `$\sim$` next to the vertical line, rotated 90 degrees, or replace the arrow with a rotated `$\cong$` symbol.

How can I implement either of these options with `xymatrix`?

Comment: To get a vertical `~`, especially in XY, I usually use `\wr`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also type `\ar[d]^*[@]{\cong}` this makes the symbol `\cong` follow the direction of the arrow, but it has some bugs, it won't work well if your arrow goes left. Or if you want to force a different direction try `\ar[d]^*[@!180]{\cong}` this rotates 180 degrees so, you'll get an upsidown `\cong`.

**EDIT**

So, I found in another post that I will cite in the comments, the solution for the arrows going left. This is a full example, with empty arrows using `@{}`.

```
\[\xymatrix{
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\\
\bullet&\bullet\ar@{}[ru]|*[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[r]|*[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[rd]|*[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[d]|*[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[ld]|*[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[l]|*[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[lu]|*[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[u]|*[@]{\cong}&\bullet\\
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet
}\]

\[\xymatrix{
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\\
\bullet&\bullet\ar@{}[ru]|*=0[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[r]|*=0[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[rd]|*=0[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[d]|*=0[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[ld]|*=0[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[l]|*=0[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[lu]|*=0[@]{\cong}
               \ar@{}[u]|*=0[@]{\cong}&\bullet\\
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet
}\]
```

The first `xymatrix` is the wrong one, and the second is the correct one. What the `=0` does is to make the box of $\cong$ cero dimensional.
[image]

Comment: This seems good; it would be better with a full example.

Comment: This is the other post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38906/problems-rotating-arrow-labels and the solution appears to trace back to the answer of Ross Moore in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/how-do-i-make-the-arrow-using-xymatrix

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `\rotatebox{90}{$\cong$}` (with `\usepackage{graphicx}`)

Comment: thanks! it only worked in pdflatex, can't really explain why

Comment: @DimaSustretov If you use a DVI viewer, be careful that rotation is not showed (but it will appear in print).

Comment: I like this, simple and effective! One can also use \rotatebox{-90}.